# php fwrite does not write öäü / utf8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, fopen, fwrite

I have been trying to solve this problem for about 1.5 hours, but I have been unable to get it to work. I also searched on Google.

The W3C Validator says that my server sends a US-ASCII header.

I wrote

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

in the XML.

I have MySQL with German text. The MySQL database is in `utf8_unicode_ci` and works as it should: it saves öäü correctly.

Now I want to create an XML file from the data saved in the MySQL database. Everything works fine, but the umlauts (öäü) are not written.

I tried to use

```
$this->rss_data .=utf8_encode(....
```

but it didn't work.

```
$this->rss_data .=utf8_decode(...
```

also didn't work.

I also tried

```
fwrite($this->rss_file, utf8_encode($this->rss_data)) or die("Error while writing rss xml");
```

This also did not work.

The saved text looks like this in my XML

> Betriebssysteme sind f&uuml ;r Computer mit h&ouml ;heren

My Firefox browser shows the öäü correctly, but I cannot get a valid RSS 2.0 feed, and so the feed entries don't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On your the desktop:**

Try to use a program which correctly handles UTF-8 encoding when opening the file. *UTF-8 without BOM and ASCII is the same on the lowest code points and some programs are determining the encoding based on a sample which not necessary contains any characters from the higher code points.* (Note: Windows' notepad.exe is not the best choice to check the file)

> The first 128 characters of Unicode, which correspond one-to-one with ASCII, are encoded using a single octet with the same binary value as ASCII, making valid ASCII text valid UTF-8-encoded Unicode as well.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Another way is to explicitly set the encoding to UTF-8 in the program and check the file with that settings.

Based on your last sentence (`My Firefox browser shows the öäü correctly, but I cannot get a valid RSS 2.0 feed, and so the feed entries don't show.`) the encoding is fine, just your program and the server's headers are incorrect.

**On the server side:**

After you confirmed that the file is in UTF-8 by opening it a program which correctly handles UTF-8 without BOM, you have to check your webserver's configuration (or at least the configuration of your subdomain).

You have to set the encoding for *.xml (or the specific xml) in the headers. If you are using pregenerated files, you have to do this in the domain's or in the server's config.

[W3C's Setting charset information in .htaccess](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset.en) article could help.

> **Specifying by extension**
>
> Use the AddCharset directive to associate the character encoding with
>   all files having a particular extension in the current directory and
>   its subdirectories. For example, to serve all files with the extension
>   .html as UTF-8, open the .htaccess file in a plain text editor and
>   type the following line:
>
> `AddCharset UTF-8 .html`
>
> The extension can be specified with or without
>   a leading dot. You can add multiple extensions to the same line. This
>   will still work if you have file names such as example.en.html or
>   example.html.en.
>
> The example will cause all files with the extension .html to be served
>   as UTF-8. The HTTP Content-Type header will contain a line that ends
>   with the 'charset' information as shown in the example that follows.
>
> `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`
>
> Note: All files with this
>   extension in all subdirectories of the current location will also be
>   served as UTF-8. If, for some reason, you need to serve the odd file
>   with a different encoding you will need to override this using
>   additional directives.
>
> Note: You can associate the character encoding with any extension
>   attached to your file. For example, suppose you do language
>   negotiation and you have pages in two languages that follow the model
>   example.en.html and example.ja.html. Let's also suppose that you are
>   happy to serve English pages using your server's ISO-8859-1 default,
>   but want to serve Japanese files in UTF-8.

**Summarizing the comments**

If you are using output escaping (`htmlentities`, `htmlspecialchars`, `strip_tags`, etc), please check that these functions are not interfering or called multiple times.

Using `htmlentities()` multiple time could lead to undesired results:

```
htmlentities('Ö') = &Ouml; (Ö in the browser)
htmlentities(htmlentities('Ö')) = &amp;Ouml; (&Ouml in the browser)
```

Comment: That seems to work okay, the header is now uff-8 too, but now its the problem that öäü looks like this &Ouml ;ffentliches can you check the validator for me please? http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.moderne-computer.at%2Frss%2Fnewfile.xml

Comment: &Ouml; is the HTML entity code for Ö. You are probably using [`htmlentites()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)  somewhere in your code. (Or you use it twice and it leads to convert the original &Ouml; to &amp;Ouml; which will be represented in the client as &Ouml;)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your header to UTF8

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought about that but i don't know how to fwrite header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); in my xml file because its php?

Comment: And: when i open the file with my html editor, the text is  f&uuml ;r Computer mit h&ouml ;heren too, so maybe its something with fwrite?